# Any options to navigate params between method of controller in spring

Tags: java, spring

I have for parameters say param1,param2,param3 which i am using in controller url of spring e.g

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/createDate/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}
public String createDate (@PathVariable(param1) int param1,
                          @PathVariable(param2) int param2,
                          @PathVariable(param3) int param3){
   return "/test/createDate";
}
```

say for example now i have same method for edit date, post date as well other method.
now i want to navigate param1,param2 and param3 between all method of controller in spring. after lot of googling i found that we can navigate params using spring webflow as form backing object. Does any one have solution without using web flow.

Comment: Define "navigate param". What does navigating a param mean to you?

Comment: What do you mean with "navigate param", keep the value of those params between different method calls ? If that's it why not store that in the HttpSession ?

Comment: @FredClose yes i want to navigate between different method calls but is there any alternative rather than HttpSession ?